# Flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe with BottomNavigationBar and SearchPage

Tags: flutter, dart

The app has a BottomNavigationBar (always visible) and when I added the search tab this error apears (Search page was writed following a tutorial from youtube). I'm not sure about how can manage the state when I leave the search page or how to restart it.

I realice error apears when no search has been performed

Can someone help to solve this error?

Here is my code

**home**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const Text(
      'Index 1: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    const Text(
      'Index 1: Events',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    SearchScreen(),
    const Text(
      'Index 3: Messages',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    ProfilePage(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: null,
        body: Center(
          child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
              label: 'Events',
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2),
              label: 'Messages',
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
            ),
          ],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black12,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ));
  }
}
```

**search**

```
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  static const historyLenght = 5;
  final List<String> _searchHistory = ['pink', 'blue'];

  late List<String> filteredSearchHistory;

  String selectedTerm = "Search";

  List<String> filterSearchTerms({
    @required String? filter,
  }) {
    if (filter != null && filter.isNotEmpty) {
      return _searchHistory.reversed
          .where((term) => term.startsWith(filter))
          .toList();
    } else {
      return _searchHistory.reversed.toList();
    }
  }

  void addSearchTerm(String term) {
    if (_searchHistory.contains(term)) {
      putSearchTermFirst(term);
      return;
    }
    _searchHistory.add(term);
    if (_searchHistory.length > historyLenght) {
      _searchHistory.removeRange(0, _searchHistory.length - historyLenght);
    }
    filteredSearchHistory = filterSearchTerms(filter: null);
  }

  void deleteSearchTerm(String term) {
    _searchHistory.removeWhere((element) => element == term);
    filteredSearchHistory = filterSearchTerms(filter: null);
  }

  void putSearchTermFirst(String term) {
    deleteSearchTerm(term);
    addSearchTerm(term);
  }

  late FloatingSearchBarController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = FloatingSearchBarController();
    filteredSearchHistory = filterSearchTerms(filter: null);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FloatingSearchBar(
        controller: controller,
        body: FloatingSearchBarScrollNotifier(
          child: SearchResultListView(
            searchTerm: selectedTerm,
          ),
        ),
        transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        title: Text(selectedTerm),
        hint: 'Search ... ',
        actions: [
          FloatingSearchBarAction.searchToClear(),
        ],
        onQueryChanged: (query) {
          setState(() {
            filteredSearchHistory = filterSearchTerms(filter: query);
          });
        },
        onSubmitted: (query) {
          setState(() {
            addSearchTerm(query);
            selectedTerm = query;
          });
          controller.close();
        },
        builder: (context, transition) {
          return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            child: Material(
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 4,
                child: Builder(builder: ((context) {
                  if (filteredSearchHistory.isEmpty &&
                      controller.query.isEmpty) {
                    return Container(
                        height: 56,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Start searching',
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ));
                  } else if (filteredSearchHistory.isEmpty) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(controller.query),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          addSearchTerm(controller.query);
                          selectedTerm = controller.query;
                        });
                        controller.close();
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: filteredSearchHistory
                            .map(
                              (e) => ListTile(
                                title: Text(e,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                leading: const Icon(Icons.history),
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      deleteSearchTerm(e);
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    putSearchTermFirst(e);
                                    selectedTerm = e;
                                  });
                                  controller.close();
                                },
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList());
                  }
                }))),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchResultListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String searchTerm;

  const SearchResultListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.searchTerm,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (searchTerm == null) {
      return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [Icon(Icons.search), Text('data')],
        ),
      );
    }
    final sBar = FloatingSearchBar.of(context);
    return ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: sBar!.style.height + sBar.style.margins.vertical),
        children: List.generate(
            50,
            (index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('Hola $searchTerm'),
                  subtitle: Text(index.toString()),
                )));
  }
}
```